# ECMA6 classes not working on IE11 with Webpack and Babel

Tags: ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, webpack-4

I am trying to get a React project to work with being packaged using Webpack and Babel using @babel/pollyfill. When I try to run on IE I get the following error...

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

It is failing here...

```
class HealthCheck extends react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Component"]{
    render(){
        return _HealthCheck_jsx__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["HealthCheckTemplate"].call(this);
    }
}
```

So I am guessing it can't handle class so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @babel/plugin-transform-classes .

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-classes

Comment: Actually shoot this is the part that isn't using babel. I am only using Babel for JSX files this is a js file. I am using webpack to bundle the js files but not babel. Maybe I will need to start with those too

Comment: Adding js to the babel loader and including this worked thanks!

Comment: What does your configuration look like now? Might be helpful for others to see it. I'm curious too.